# Adapting a script to count actions performed

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have this code to create a binary tree and, at each insertion, checks if its balanced. If its not, perform the rotations to balance the tree.

The balancing and tree's creating is working properly. However, I also want to count how many times the code rotate the tree to balance it.

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 1
 
class AVL_Tree(object):
 
    def insert(self, root, key):
     
        # Step 1 - Perform normal BST
        if not root:
            return TreeNode(key)
        elif key < root.val:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, key)
        else:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, key)
 
        # Step 2 - Update the height of the
        # ancestor node
        root.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(root.left),
                           self.getHeight(root.right))
 
        # Step 3 - Get the balance factor
        balance = self.getBalance(root)
 
        # Step 4 - If the node is unbalanced,
        # then try out the 4 cases
        
        # Case 1 - Left Left
        
        if balance > 1 and key < root.left.val:
            return self.rightRotate(root)
            
 
        # Case 2 - Right Right
        if balance < -1 and key > root.right.val:
            return self.leftRotate(root)
 
        # Case 3 - Left Right
        if balance > 1 and key > root.left.val:
            root.left = self.leftRotate(root.left)
            return self.rightRotate(root)
 
        # Case 4 - Right Left
        if balance < -1 and key < root.right.val:
            root.right = self.rightRotate(root.right)
            return self.leftRotate(root)
 
        return root
 
    def leftRotate(self, z):
 
        y = z.right
        T2 = y.left
 
        # Perform rotation
        y.left = z
        z.right = T2
 
        # Update heights
        z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left),
                         self.getHeight(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left),
                         self.getHeight(y.right))
 
        # Return the new root
        return y
 
    def rightRotate(self, z):
 
        y = z.left
        T3 = y.right
 
        # Perform rotation
        y.right = z
        z.left = T3
 
        # Update heights
        z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left),
                        self.getHeight(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left),
                        self.getHeight(y.right))
 
        # Return the new root
        return y
 
    def getHeight(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0
 
        return root.height
 
    def getBalance(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0
 
        return self.getHeight(root.left) - self.getHeight(root.right)
 
    def preOrder(self, root):
 
        if not root:
            return
 
        print("{0} ".format(root.val), end="")
        self.preOrder(root.left)
        self.preOrder(root.right)
```

I want to modify step 4 to count how many times the code rotate the binary tree to balance it.

What I did to count the first rotation Left_left:

```
 # Case 1 - Left Left
        ll=0
        if balance > 1 and key < root.left.val:
            ll+=1
            return self.rightRotate(root),ll
         print(ll)
```

But Is not working as it is printing 0,0,0,0...

How can I properly count how many times each rotation is performed?

Example of a tree I am balancing:

```
myTree = AVL_Tree()
root = None
 
root = myTree.insert(root, 10)
root = myTree.insert(root, 3)
root = myTree.insert(root, 2)
root = myTree.insert(root, 5)
root = myTree.insert(root, 7)
root = myTree.insert(root, 6)
 
"""The constructed AVL Tree would be
             5
           /  \
         3     7
        /     / \
       2     6   10
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of a tree you are balancing?

Comment: @FraserLangton Sure thing.  I just updated the code to show an example. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looks like you need to be aware of the scope you are storing your count variables in, whenever you call insert your count variables are in that method's scope and so a reset every time you call it. In my code below I get `1 0 1 1` for `ll, rr, lr` and `rl` respectively.

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 1


class AVL_Tree(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ll, self.rr, self.lr, self.rl = 0, 0, 0, 0

    def insert(self, root, key):

        # Step 1 - Perform normal BST
        if not root:
            return TreeNode(key)
        elif key < root.val:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, key)
        else:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, key)

        # Step 2 - Update the height of the
        # ancestor node
        root.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(root.left),
                              self.getHeight(root.right))

        # Step 3 - Get the balance factor
        balance = self.getBalance(root)

        # Step 4 - If the node is unbalanced,
        # then try out the 4 cases

        # Case 1 - Left Left

        if balance > 1 and key < root.left.val:
            self.ll += 1
            return self.rightRotate(root)

        # Case 2 - Right Right
        if balance < -1 and key > root.right.val:
            self.rr += 1
            return self.leftRotate(root)

        # Case 3 - Left Right
        if balance > 1 and key > root.left.val:
            self.lr += 1
            root.left = self.leftRotate(root.left)
            return self.rightRotate(root)

        # Case 4 - Right Left
        if balance < -1 and key < root.right.val:
            self.rl += 1
            root.right = self.rightRotate(root.right)
            return self.leftRotate(root)

        return root

    def leftRotate(self, z):

        y = z.right
        T2 = y.left

        # Perform rotation
        y.left = z
        z.right = T2

        # Update heights
        z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left),
                           self.getHeight(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left),
                           self.getHeight(y.right))

        # Return the new root
        return y

    def rightRotate(self, z):

        y = z.left
        T3 = y.right

        # Perform rotation
        y.right = z
        z.left = T3

        # Update heights
        z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left),
                           self.getHeight(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left),
                           self.getHeight(y.right))

        # Return the new root
        return y

    def getHeight(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0

        return root.height

    def getBalance(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0

        return self.getHeight(root.left) - self.getHeight(root.right)

    def preOrder(self, root):

        if not root:
            return

        print("{0} ".format(root.val), end="")
        self.preOrder(root.left)
        self.preOrder(root.right)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTree = AVL_Tree()
    root = None

    root = myTree.insert(root, 10)
    root = myTree.insert(root, 3)
    root = myTree.insert(root, 2)
    root = myTree.insert(root, 5)
    root = myTree.insert(root, 7)
    root = myTree.insert(root, 6)

    print(myTree.ll, myTree.rr, myTree.lr, myTree.rl)
```